# Android Custom Camera Pictures when Captured and saved Picture is Totally Black

Tags: android, camera, android-ndk

Hello to all Android Dev.

I am working with custom camera (Android NDK) where i will apply some filter at live cam. ok for now but when i captured the picture and saved it the pictures goes to totally black image. first i convert captured image to Bitmap and the decode it , for more understanding i am here sending you my Complete code....

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.downloadToolbal);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    context = CameraActivity.this;
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    cameraEngine = new CameraEngine(this);

    MagicEngine.Builder builder = new MagicEngine.Builder();
    magicEngine = builder.build((MagicCameraView) findViewById(R.id.gl_surface_camera));
    camera_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cameraImg);
    cameraSurface = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_surface);
    cameraSurface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           cameraEngine.takePicture(mPicture);
        }
    });

    mFilterListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.filter_listView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    mFilterListView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new FilterAdapter(this, types);
    mFilterListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.setOnFilterChangeListener(new FilterAdapter.onFilterChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFilterChanged(MagicFilterType filterType) {
            magicEngine.setFilter(filterType);
        }
    });
}
```

also See here

```
  private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        dir_image2 = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                File.separator+"My Custom Folder");
        dir_image2.mkdirs();


        File tmpFile = new File(dir_image2,"TempImage.jpg");
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        bmp1 = decodeFile(tmpFile);
        bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp1,cameraSurface.getWidth(), cameraSurface.getHeight(),true);
        camera_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        tmpFile.delete();
        savePicture();

    }
};


private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        // Decode image size
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
        fis.close();
        int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1000;
        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(
                    2,
                    (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                            / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                            / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b;
}
```

If you wanted to know MagicEngine Class then here is Bellow

```
public class MagicEngine {
private static MagicEngine magicEngine;

public static MagicEngine getInstance(){
    if(magicEngine == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("MagicEngine must be built first");
    else
        return magicEngine;
}

private MagicEngine(Builder builder){

}

public void setFilter(MagicFilterType type){
    MagicParams.magicBaseView.setFilter(type);
}

public void savePicture(File file, SavePictureTask.OnPictureSaveListener listener){
    SavePictureTask savePictureTask = new SavePictureTask(file, listener);
    MagicParams.magicBaseView.savePicture(savePictureTask);
}

public void startRecord(){
    if(MagicParams.magicBaseView instanceof MagicCameraView)
        ((MagicCameraView)MagicParams.magicBaseView).changeRecordingState(true);
}

public void stopRecord(){
    if(MagicParams.magicBaseView instanceof MagicCameraView)
        ((MagicCameraView)MagicParams.magicBaseView).changeRecordingState(false);
}

public void setBeautyLevel(int level){
    if(MagicParams.magicBaseView instanceof MagicCameraView && MagicParams.beautyLevel != level) {
        MagicParams.beautyLevel = level;
        ((MagicCameraView) MagicParams.magicBaseView).onBeautyLevelChanged();
    }
}

public void switchCamera(){
    CameraEngine.switchCamera();
}

public static class Builder{

    public MagicEngine build(MagicBaseView magicBaseView) {
        MagicParams.context = magicBaseView.getContext();
        MagicParams.magicBaseView = magicBaseView;
        return new MagicEngine(this);
    }

    public Builder setVideoPath(String path){
        MagicParams.videoPath = path;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setVideoName(String name){
        MagicParams.videoName = name;
        return this;
    }

}
```

}

Also see the .xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/camera_surface"
    android:layout_below="@+id/downloadToolbal"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cameraImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.seu.magicfilter.widget.MagicCameraView
        android:id="@+id/gl_surface_camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/filter_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Comment: See my answer.If you have any query let me know.

Comment: Hello @Andy Developer Thanks for your Reply... well this is helpful but this is not according to my code.. could you please explain it throughout my code really appreciate to you

Comment: Welcome :) did you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes if you explore my code i am also doing in such a way that you suggested...

Comment: Yes I was seen that but their are some changes that's why I was post the answer. Just try to replace this with yours and its done.

Comment: could you please highlight those changes.. Really appreciate you.. because i did not found that

Comment: Where is Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG or PNG in which you want to convert. Where is the rotation of picture from which camera front or back you capture you need to rotate the image. Where is ByteArrayOutputStream and FileOutputStream to write the file and many more things too bro.

Comment: Can you please send me your email where i can send you my complete code.. i have been tried the things you highlighted... Please give send me your email where i can send you my complete code... really appreciate to you....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This is working code of my google play application.

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = new File(photoPath.toString());
        byte[] pictureBytes;
        Bitmap thePicture;
        Matrix m;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
        BitmapFactory.Options opt;

        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = parameters.getPictureSize();

            int height11 = size.height;
            int width11 = size.width;
            float mb = (width11 * height11) / 1024000;

            if (mb > 4f)
                opt.inSampleSize = 2;

            thePicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);

            if (cameraFront) {
                m = new Matrix();
                m.postRotate(270);
                Utils.freeMemory();
                thePicture = Bitmap.createBitmap(thePicture, 0, 0, thePicture.getWidth(), thePicture.getHeight(), m, true);

                bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thePicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                pictureBytes = bos.toByteArray();
            } else {
                m = new Matrix();
                m.postRotate(90);
                Utils.freeMemory();
                thePicture = Bitmap.createBitmap(thePicture, 0, 0, thePicture.getWidth(), thePicture.getHeight(), m, true);

                bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thePicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                pictureBytes = bos.toByteArray();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(pictureBytes);
            fos.close();
            if (thePicture != null) {
                if (!thePicture.isRecycled()) {
                    thePicture.recycle();
                }
                thePicture = null;
            }
            bos.close();
            m = null;     
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.error(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.error(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.error(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```